# Set ID for column in foreach loop in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am generating a table in MVC4 like this:

```
 foreach(var item in model.details)
 {
    <tr>
       <td>
           @item.status
       </td>
    </tr>
  }
```

My question is, how can I assign an ID to that status field?  What I want to do is use jQuery and AJAX to modify the value in the database and return with the new status and update only that one column in that one row with the new status, without having to refresh the entire list.  I would think that this is the only way to do it, but if there is a better way please let me know.

I have tired

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.status, new { @id = "status@item.status"})
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.status, new { @id = "status" + @item.status})
```

Neither of which work.  I also need to add a click event to the column and can't seem to find a way to do that either.

Comment: Unless you have created a custom display template, `@Html.DisplayFor()` will only output the value (not an element). Add it the the enclosing `<td>` element

Comment: DisplayFor HtmlHelper only generate text, so you can't set ID for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.something) can not set Id directly. if you want to
 use @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.status) with id you will need some helper.

This is already explained here - [Html.DisplayFor — Is it possible to have this control generate an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960623/mvc3-html-displayfor-is-it-possible-to-have-this-control-generate-an-id)

Other wise there is a simple way  as-

```
 foreach(var item in model.details)
     {
        <tr>
           <td id="status_@Html.Raw(item.status)" class="Clickable_td_class">
               @item.status
           </td>
        </tr>
      }
```

If you have common status across multiple rows so you need to change your Id unique. you can do this as -

```
foreach(var item in model.details.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i + 1 }))
     {
        <tr>
           <td id="status_@Html.Raw(item.Data.status)_@Html.Raw(item.Index )" class="Clickable_td_class">
               @item.Data.status
           </td>
        </tr>
      }
```

Please use `@Html.Raw(item.status)` instead of `@item.status`in Id.

Then you can write your jquery something like below -

```
$("Clickable_td_class").click(function(){
    var current_Id = "#" + $(this).attr("Id");
    $.ajax({
        // All ajax params 
        // and  on success just replace html of particular element as -
        // $(this).html(your success reponse);
        // OR
        //$(current_Id).html(your success reponse);

     });
});
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Add to each one of your items in the model an Id and for each row set row id property to be equal to this item.Id:

```
   foreach(var item in model.details)
     {
        <tr id='@item.Id'>
           <td id="staus_@item.Id">
               @item.status
           </td>
        </tr>
      }
```

And for update (assuming the you receive a json with id and a new value for status)

```
$ajax(...).done(function(data){    
  $('#status_' +  data.id).html(data.status);
});
```

Comment: that got me part of the way there, but setting the value does not work.

      function changeval(id) {
      $("#status" + id).html('changed');
       }

the button sends the id for that column/row which I set to 
        <td id = "status+@item.id">

Comment: <td id = "status+@item.id"> renders to "status+1" not to "status1" assuming that id is 1and $("#status" + id) is "status1"